# MVC 5 Razor view displays Linq errors but page renders correctly

Tags: linq, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I frequently get errors such as displayed in the picture below when using Linq in a Razor view. I have obviously added the @using System.Linq include on the top of the page (although it will strangely work without it), but still get the errors no matter what i try.

Is there any way to prevent these errors from appearing? I know i shouldn't be using too much code inside a view, perhaps the best solution would be to build the list in the code, use it here and stop worrying about editor syntax errors?

[Razor Linq Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVl6v.png)

Comment: What's the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: The type IEnumerable<> is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.

It looks like VS is really confused. It doesn't matter if i have @using System.Collections.Generic or not and it even complains the directive is unnecessary.

Comment: This kind of problems is often in some way related to the config files. Have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38273842/the-type-ienumerable-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced
You can also try to create a test project and see if everything works as expected there and if it does, compare the web config files for possible differences... Note that there are two of those in each mvc project...

Comment: Thank you. That answer was the solution to the problem. Shame i cannot vote it up or even comment but at least i can thank you for your help :)

Comment: You're welcome. I have copied my comment as an answer. You can mark it as accepted if you want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of problems is often in some way related to the config files. Have you seen this answer?

[The type 'IEnumerable<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38273842/the-type-ienumerable-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced)

You can also try to create a test project and see if everything works as expected there and if it does, compare the web config files for possible differences... Note that there are two of those in each mvc project...

Comment: You're welcome. You'd do good to upvote that guy's answer which helped you when you are able to. I already did so...