# the type ienumerable is defined in an assembly that is not referenced,

Tags: .net, .net-standard

I'm unable to build the solution with following error message,

the type ienumerable is defined in an assembly that is not referenced, you must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral,

Comment: Please provide more information. What type of project is this occurring in (class library, console application, etc.)? What framework are you targeting? What version of Visual Studio are you using? Without more detail, I can suggest 1) add a reference to the NETStandard.Library.NETFramework package 2) ensure you have .NET Core 2.0 SDK installed 3) make sure you're using <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"> in your csproj file if it is a .NET Standard project and 4) add a reference to <Reference Include="netstandard" /> if it is a .NET Framework 4.7+ project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with adding reference to netstandard 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699238/problems-with-adding-reference-to-netstandard-2-0)

Comment: Since I can't flag after finding a better sub, possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38273842/the-type-ienumerable-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced